# How does this clang code work?

Tags: c++, clang

In clang's `ActOnIfStmt` function, we have:

```
return Owned(new (Context) IfStmt(Context, IfLoc, ConditionVar, ConditionExpr,
    thenStmt, ElseLoc, elseStmt));
```

I'm under the impression that `Context` is a pointer type, but it's a class type. How does this work, and what does this code do?

Comment: This is called ["placement new"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/placement-new.html), which is used to instantiate objects at a specific memory location pointed by `Context`. So `Context` is (as far as I know) in fact a pointer type. `IfStmt` is the class type here.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ASTContext_8h-source.html - look at lines 1314 and following. Doesn't look like a standard form of `operator new` (cc @Insilico).

Comment: Thank you ,Mat.i understand it now ,thank you very much!